# Why am I getting an exception when I try to set the value of a cell in Excel using Perl's Win32::OLE?

Tags: perl, excel, win32ole

I am getting the error `Win32::OLE<0.1709> error 0x80020009: "Exception occurred" in PROPERTYPUT "Value"` at line 109.

The code in is Perl.

```
foreach my $ref_array1 (@$array1) {     # loop through the array
 foreach my $col1 (@$ref_array1) {     
   foreach my $ref_array2 (@$array2) {     # loop through the array   
     foreach my $col2 (@$ref_array2) {      
       if ($col1 eq $col2)
        {

             this is line 109: **$worksheet1->Cells($j,1)->{'Value'} = $col1;**

             $j++;
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.
Thankyou

Comment: user402705: I reformatted your question to make it more readable. Take a look at it for future reference.

Comment: And, try to come up with a short but complete example we can run that still exhibits the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The following incomplete example works (i.e., it puts 5 in cell `A1`):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

use Win32::OLE qw(in with);
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Excel';
$Win32::OLE::Warn = 3;

my $excel = get_excel();
$excel->{Visible} = 1;

my $book = $excel->Workbooks->Add;
my $sheet = $book->Worksheets->Add;
$sheet->{Name} = 'Perl Win32-OLE Example';

my $range = $sheet->Cells(1,1);
$range->{Value} = 5;
$range->AutoFormat;

sub get_excel {
    my $excel;

    unless ( eval {
            $excel = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Excel.Application')
    }) {
        die $@, "\n";
    }

    unless(defined $excel) {
        $excel = Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application', sub { $_[0]->Quit })
            or die "Oops, cannot start Excel: ",
                   Win32::OLE->LastError, "\n";
    }
    return $excel;
}
```

See also my [Perl Win32::OLE example](http://www.unur.com/comp/ppp/perl-win32-ole-excel-ex1.html).